# Is there a way to declare and use a VBA variable as long as the Excel workbook is open?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have a deep knowledge of VBA fundamental programming, I just know how to declare variables, use methods, create some objects and a very weak knowledge of creating classes to make new event handlers.

My question is "Is there any way I can declare a variable to automatically give it a value and use this variable as long as my Excel workbook is open?"

I have written these codes in "ThisWorkBook" and "Sheet1" Module and using a Global variable called Wb to test if this variable remains as long as my workbook is open but it seems it does not.

In "ThisWorkbook" Module:

```
Public Wb As Workbook

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   set Wb=ThisWorkbook
End sub
```

In "Sheet1" Module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   MsgBox Wb.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. That is called a Public variable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Comment: @braX I declared a "Public" variable before Workbook_open event handler at "ThisWorkbook" module but it doesn't seem to retain it's value after this Workbook_open procedure ends.  I used this variable (which name is Wb) in "Sheet1" module to test if it works but it doesn't. I am going to add my code so it may help.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is not a module. It's an Excel Object. Right click on the VBAProject, then click Insert, then click Module. Put the declaration there instead.

Comment: **1.** Declare `Public Wb As Workbook` in a module **2.** If Sheet1 is the active sheet when the workbook open then `Worksheet_Activate()` for that sheet will not work. Move to another sheet and then come back to Sheet1 and that event will fire.

Comment: @braX I know I should avoid saying "Thanks" and "Thumbs Up" in comment section but You did a huge favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` is not a `Module`. It's an `Excel Object`.

- Right click on the VBAProject
- then click Insert
- then click Module.

Put this declaration there instead.

```
Public Wb As Workbook
```